# How to monitor quality of unreliable link over time?

Tags: networking, monitoring

We have ISP that provides us with a shoddy service. It usually works, but there are times when it works really bad, drops connections and gets awfully slow. Sadly, our contract doesn't have SLA clause that we can invoke in this instance.

How can I best measure both inbound latency outbound latency and packet loss? These are specific parameters that I think would tell me if we had an outage (even a short one for less than a minute), if there were any delays due to congested link, and so on. Having nice, informative graphs would be a plus.

Comment: The ultimate answer for this question is: **Yes**. However, the question is way too wide, since there are [tens of network monitoring systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems) that could serve your purposes.

Comment: Given that question is too wide, could you possibly suggest how to re-word it, as to avoid being closed, and to get more relevant answer?

Comment: I'd go with smokeping, you have on the same graph latency and packet loss

Answer (score 3):

Cloud monitoring is probably the best approach here...

Look at something like: [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com).

The contract with your ISP likely has an [SLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) of some sort. They may be able to provide you their graphs as well.

I mean, what's the purpose of monitoring the connection? Is there a disagreement about the service quality? If it's not sufficient vis-à-vis your contract, the onus is on the provider to meet that standard.

Comment: Even though I knew about Pingdom, it didn't cross my mind to do reverse-testing (from outside of my network). Good idea.

Comment: Sadly, our contract doesn't include SLA. There is a disagreement, yes, and I am trying to prove that they are not fulfilling their contractual obligation to provide us with technical means of having consistent access to internet. It is messy...

Comment: Tried Pingdom for several days, but I don't like that 1 minute is the best granularity they offer. Also, I am under the impression that they ping from various sites around the net, resulting in probably artificial latency measurements. It was really painless to configure, but I suspect there may be more to then what it is telling me.

Answer (score 2):

The two utilities I have used for this type of thing are Smokeping (http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) and MRTG (http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/). Having said that, however, I would not be surprised to see this question closed as off-topic/product recommendation.

Comment: After trying Pingdom for several days with inconclusive results, it may be time to try smokeping, it may prove more useful.